# How to configure symfony 1.4 project on localhost

Tags: localhost, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony, I want to run one already built project to localhost, so I put source code into localhost folder. But still getting error as follow:

> Notice: Undefined variable: categorys in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/haute-master/apps/admin/modules/category/templates/indexSuccess.php
>   on line 12
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/haute-master/apps/admin/modules/category/templates/indexSuccess.php
>   on line 12

Code at 12th line:

foreach ($categorys as $category):

Comment: paste your `admin/modules/category/actions/actions.class.php` and `admin/modules/category/templates/indexSuccess.php`

Comment: It placed at that location

Comment: You need to show us your code, we can't guess what's wrong without seeing your code

Comment: edit your question and paste it into question or use some service like http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I found $this->categorys = Doctrine_Core::getTable('category')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->execute(); in action.php

Comment: so you probably don't have any data in `category` table

Comment: I put some value in database but getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template know nothing about `$categorys` variable. Check your `apps/admin/modules/category/actions/actions.class.php`, look for action which is run in this case and search for `$this->categorys` because this is apparently missing